# Realm in appdelegate.swift not working on other files

Tags: ios, swift, realm, swift4

This is a simple one probably but am I doing something wrong here :

I have this in my appdelegate.swift :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    //configure Firebase
    FirebaseApp.configure()

let realm = try! Realm()

    return true
}
```

then I want to use refer to it in my view controller files like this :

```
do {
        try realm.write {
            realm.add(workoutData)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Sorry no good")
    }
```

but it says "use of unresolved identifier 'realm'".

But I thought the point of putting in app delegate was so you didn't need to do the 'let realm = try! Realm()' on every single view controller?

I have a firebase instance which is configured in appdelegate by doing :

```
    FirebaseApp.configure()
```

and that works fine.

Am I missing something here?  I can't find another answer that covers this so basically (there are some relating to migrations etc) so I'm assuming this is something really simple!

Comment: Where exactly did you declare `realm` inside the AppDelegate.swift file? Most probably you declared it inside the class as an instance property rather than as a global variable. Btw keeping a global reference to Realm is a bad idea for several reasons (other than the usual reasons why not to use global variables, `Realm` is thread-safe, so keeping a global reference to it can easily lead to threading issues), so you shouldn't do it just to save you from having to create new references to your `Realm` instance.

Comment: thanks i have updated the code snippet to show where it is - okay this makes complete sense - so I should always declare the realm instance in any view controller that needs it? I didn't know that thanks!

Comment: That declaration is completely wrong. That's not even an instance property of your app delegate class, but a local variable inside the function it is declared in. As I've already stated, you can create a global variable (create it outside any class/type declarations), but that will rather sooner than later lead to threading issues, so yes, I suggest creating references to your `Realm` with a smaller scope (either an instance property of each class where you need it or simply a local variable if you only use it in one function in a class).

Comment: thank you! this is really helpful and answers my question (as well as gives me better understanding generally!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David Pastor answered this for me..

For any noobs that come this way....

You shouldn't declare it as a global variable anyway because that leads to issues as your app scales and if you did then the way i've done it wouldn't be right anyway!